# Transform an array according to elements' odd/even positions

Tags: coffeescript

Given an array with an even number of elements, how can I turn it into an array of objects with properties 'id' equal to odd elements and 'score' equal to even elements.

example:

```
originalArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
targetArray   = [{ id: 0, score: 1 }, { id: 2, score: 3 }, { id:4, score: 5 }]
```

Comment: `originalArray` doesn't have an odd number of elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything better than a straight forward loop:

```
targetArray = for i in [0 ... originalArray.length ] by 2
    { id: originalArray[i], score: originalArray[i + 1] }
```

You can write that in different ways or wrap it in a function but it'll probably be a step-2 loop in the end.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gW3xj/

Comment: Answer accepted with one caveat: the loop should end at originalArray.length - 1

Comment: @RunningTurtle: Look up the difference between `..` and `...` in CoffeeScript, the loop is correct as written.

Comment: But it is easy to miss so if you don't see the usual `-1` then look for an extra dot.